# Return Method with No Parameters Involving String Array

Tags: java, methods

I am attempting to create a method called `get8BallAnswers`. The method is supposed to build the array of possible String answers and return the entire array. It is also not supposed to have any parameters.

My array has a size of 12 so I am trying to write the method as

```
public String {} get8BallAnswers() {
    return new String {12};
}
```

However it is not working. I am not sure how to fix it in order for it to work.

Also if it helps this is what my array looks like

```
String[] responses = { "Yes, of course!", "Without a doubt, yes",
    "You can count on it.", "For sure!", "Ask me later.",
    "I'm not sure.", "I can't tell you right now.",
    "I'll tell you after my nap.", "No way!", "I don't think so.",
    "Without a doubt, no.", "The answer is clearly No." };
```

Comment: Explain `not working`

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you write `String { }` for the `return` type. This is not how we specify arrays, you should write `String[]`. And if you want to create an empty array with size `12` you should write `return new String[12];` If you want to return `responses` you should just `return responses;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not correct syntax

```
public String {} get8BallAnswers() {
             return new String {12};
}
```

The correct format would be

```
private String [] get8BallAnswers() {
    String[] responses = {"Yes, of course!", "Without a doubt, yes", 
                          "You can count on it.", "For sure!", "Ask me later.", 
                          "I'm not sure.", "I can't tell you right now.",
                          "I'll tell you after my nap.", "No way!", "I don't think so.", 
                          "Without a doubt, no.", "The answer is clearly No."};

    return responses;
}
```